# Run Time Error "424": Object Required when copying data from one workbook to an active one

Tags: excel, vba, object, runtime-error

Good Evening.

I have been working on the following project, which is generating several 424 Run Time Errors.

The following public sub is declared in ThisWorkbook:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim rolandPath As String 'Declares global string variable rolandFile for RoLanD's filepath
Dim rolandSource As Workbook ' declares global workbook variable rolandSource for RoLanD listed in rolandPath
Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook 'declares global workbook variable destinationWorkbook for Extract Tool
Dim storeID As Integer ' Declares global integer variable storeID for Store's 4 digit ID
Dim tFocus As Long 'Declares global long variable tFocus for current Tab in focus
Dim cFocus As Long 'Declares global long variable cFocus for current Column in focus
Dim rFocus As Long 'Declares global long variable rFocus for current Row in focus
Dim rRecord As Long 'Declares global long variable rRecord for current Row being recorded to

Call DataConnect

End Sub
```

The remainder of this code is in Module1:

```
Sub DataConnect()
MsgBox ("Please select your RoLanD file. If you are asked to enter your password, please do this. If you select Cancel, you may need to exit and restart this application.") 'Explains to the user what to do next.
FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename 'Opens dialogue for user to select RoLanD file
    If FilePath <> "" Then 'Checks that the filepath is completed
       rolandPath = FilePath 'Stores the filepath for RoLanD into the variable rolandFile
    End If
storeID = InputBox("Please enter your Store's four digit ID (EG: 0123). If you enter this incorrectly, this may result in your colleagues records being incorrectly applied", "Enter Store ID") ' Prompts user to enter store ID, then stores it as integer storeID
MsgBox ("Thank you. Your current RoLanD data will now be copied. This will leave your data intact in RoLanD, so please do not be concerned. Please select OK to continue.") 'Gives a message to reassure user.

cFocus = "Q" 'Sets the Column in focus to Column Q
rFocus = 5 'Sets the Row in focus to the fifth one
rRecord = 1 'Sets the row the record is being recorded to as the first one
tFocus = 1 'Sets the Tab in focus to the first one

Set rolandSource = Workbooks.Open(rolandPath)

On Error Resume Next ' tells DB to move on when error is reached
Do
    Call tInFocus
    tFocus = tFocus + 1 'Adds tab (worksheet) in focus up one
Loop Until Err.Number <> 0 'breaks when no more worksheets available

MsgBox ("Data is fully copied.")
End Sub

Sub tInFocus()
cFocus = "Q" 'Sets the Column in focus to Column Q
rFocus = 5 'Sets the Row in focus to the fifth one
If rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range("Q4").Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'Ends subroutine if Q4 is empty, which means no data on this RoLanD tab
Do
    Do
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Sheets(tFocus).Range("B" & rFocus) 'Copies employee number in focus to destination
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("B" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & "4") ' Copies learning title in focus to destination
        ThisWorkbook.Wksheets("1").Range("C" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & rFocus) 'Copies learning completion date in focus to destination
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("D" & rRecord).Value = storeID 'Copies store ID to row in focus
        rRecord = rRecord + 1 'Moves line being recorded to on one
        cFocus = Chr(Asc(cFocus) + 1) 'Moves column in focus up one
    Loop Until rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & 4) = "" 'Breaks loop when end column reached
    rFocus = rFocus + 1 'Moves row in focus up one
    cFocus = "Q" 'Resets cFocus to Column Q
Loop Until rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(B & rFocus) = "" 'Breaks loop when end row reached

End Sub
```

There are two issues I am having; the first is the **Loop Until Err.Number <> 0** is ending after the first instance. This should end the loop when tFocus is at a value where no worksheet exists.

The second, and larger issue, is that the following lines are generating **Run Time Error "424": Object Required** error messages in the debug window:

**If rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range("Q4").Value = "" Then Exit Sub**

**ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Sheets(tFocus).Range("B" & rFocus) 'Copies employee number in focus to destination**

**ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("B" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & "4") ' Copies learning title in focus to destination**

**ThisWorkbook.Wksheets("1").Range("C" & rRecord).Value = rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & rFocus) 'Copies learning completion date in focus to destination**

**ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("D" & rRecord).Value = storeID 'Copies store ID to row in focus**

**Loop Until rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & 4) = "" 'Breaks loop when end column reached**

**Loop Until rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(B & rFocus) = "" 'Breaks loop when end row reached**

I have read several articles and tried varying approaches, including changing the lines that copy data to the following:

```
rolandSource.Activate
rolandSource.Worksheet(tFocus).Cell("B" & rFocus).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Call("A" & rRecord).Paste
```

This produced the same results.

Any ideas or support would be greatly appreciated. I am returning to coding after a loooong break, and know I am probably doing something really silly, but can't figure out what!

Thanks in anticipation, Dan

Comment: Al lthe variables you declare in `Workbook_Open` are only visible to that procedure: they will not be accessible to (eg) `Dataconnect`.  Add `Option Explicit` at the top of each of your modules and it will alert you if you're trying to assign values to "undeclared" variables

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams this has helped me _a lot_! I am now getting output as I anticipated, however when I hit **Loop Until rolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Range(cFocus & 4) = ""**, the code is breaking, displaying _"Run Time Error 1004: Application Defined or Object-Defined error."_ - I have tried both "" and NULL but neither seem to work (in fact NULL causes an infinite loop where I have to CTRL+BREAK).

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the values of `tFocus` and `cFocus` when it errors?

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams that's the problem! I was using **chr(asc** to move columns up incrementally - which doesn't work past "z", the error was occurring when cFocus was "[". I have rewritten using **cell()** instead of **range()** so I can reference by numerical position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TimWilliams, who pointed out that I was not declaring my variables correctly. Also, an error with using chr(asc to change columns doesn't work past "z" (obviously when you think about it), so I changer to referencing using cell().